# odoo14 button does not get added to the oe button box

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-14

I have added

```
<div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
    <field name="active" invisible="1"/>
    <button type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-archive" name="toggle_active" string="Archive" attrs="{'invisible': [('active', '=', False)]}"/>
    <button type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-archive" name="toggle_active" string="Restore" attrs="{'invisible': [('active', '=', True)]}"/>
</div>
<widget name="web_ribbon" title="Archived" bg_color="bg-danger" attrs="{'invisible': [('active', '=', True)]}"/>
```

this to the sheet of the form of my view but unfortunately, the buttons do not get displayed.

This is what I want:

[image: image with archive action]

But this is what it looks like:

[image: image without archive action]

what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the button box but the action menu. IIRC you can't add anything there by extending a view, but by creating actions.

And if you want to add the archive functionality in Odoo 14+ you just have to add the field `active` invisible in your form view. That should be enough and is an exception to my statement before ;-)

If you need the ribbon, you have to add that, too, like in your example.

Edit: seems you should not put the field `active` into a `div` or probably the `button_box` `div`.

Comment: can you further explain what you mean with active invisible?
I have added
`active = fields.Boolean('Active', default=True)`
To my model, what do I have to change?
@CZoellner

Comment: I meant adding it to the view as normal field but with `invisible="1"`. But i see now, that you've already done that in your view. So the action "Archive" should be there already, hmm.

Comment: Maybe the div around it has some effect on it. Try to get it outside of that div.

Comment: Putting it outside of the div solved the problem. If you edit your answer that it contains it or post a new answer I will mark it as correct! Thank you for helping

Comment: added it. Thanks for the hint.